# How can I find a transaction on my Bittrex Ripple address with tag?

Tags: wallet, ripple, bittrex, ripple-api

Bittrex didn't deposit the XRP due to some technical issues and now asking for transaction Id. How can I find the transactions on my Ripple address and tag that happened a few days back?

I tried looking up on Bithomp, XRP Charts, but nothing is that helpful. If there's an API which I can program, I can do that as well.

Please help, thank you!

Comment: I will put this question on a bounty, if you can even help with the list of transactions on XRP address and tag, I will be more than happy to give that bounty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bithomp now shows transaction hash (id), in the transaction block. You need to press on the orange i. The problem that is shows only first or last 200 transactions. You can use ripple api, to get the info as well.
https://ripple.com/build/data-api-v2/

Comment: Thank you, I was able to find this solution weeks ago. I am upvoting and accepting it for others to people to know about it as well :) thank you!